# Android, xml: Constraint layout

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout

Может ли `constraint layout` обрести закругленные углы, если к нему применить заранее созданную `shape` с `<corners android:radius=12dp />`?

Comment: contact_rounded_view.xml: ```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="12dp" />
</shape>```

Comment: Мой ConstraintLayout: `android:background="@drawable/contact_rounded_view"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может. Правда только визуально, в качестве фона. Это не ограничит область видимости/отрисовки дочерних элементов.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#000" />
    <corners android:radius="12dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Даже визуально не работает, к сожалению.

Comment: @ftelnov значит вы что-то не так делаете. Больше из вопроса ничего не могу вам сказать (мало информации).

Comment: Добавил информацию в вопрос.

Comment: @ftelnov обновил ответ

Comment: Воу, это действительно помогло. Однако, пока лишь частично - левый край не закруглился. Но, думаю, своими силами я это исправлю. Но как заливка на это все дело повлияла?